# Implementing localstorage with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

I've been trying to implement localstorage using ngStorage in this AngularJS app I've been working on. Debugging I keep finding data type issues and errors even though everything appears fixed.

This is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/IpPDb4

```
// app.js

var app = angular.module('noteMate', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Notes) {

  $scope.notes = Notes.entries;
  $scope.tempNote = {};
  var index;

  $scope.save = function() {
    Notes.save($scope.tempNote);
    $scope.clear();
  };

  $scope.del = function(idx) {
    Notes.del(idx);
  };

  $scope.edit = function(idx) {
    $scope.tempNote = angular.copy($scope.notes[idx]);
    index = idx;
  };

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.tempNote = {};
  };

  $scope.saveEdit = function() {
    $scope.notes[index] = $scope.tempNote;
  };

  $scope.mouse = false;

});

app.service('Notes', function(){
  this.saved = $localStorage.getItem('notes');
  this.entries = ($localStorage.getItem('notes')!==null) ? JSON.parse(this.saved) :
  [{title: "Hey", desc: "This is a sample note. Add your own note by clicking the button below. :)"}];

  $localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(this.entries));

  this.save = function(entry) {
    this.entries.push(entry);
    $localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(this.entries));
  };

  this.del = function(idx) {
    this.entries.splice(idx, 1);
    $localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(this.entries));
  };

});
```

Any solutions for the problem and explanation for the issue?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @DarshakGajjar Sorry Darshak, I wasn't finished typing when I hit return. Now updated

Comment: did you forget to inject $localstorage service into Notes service?

Comment: @Nils yes! I updated that in the plunk and still no avail

Answer (score 0):

When working with a `$localStorage` service, you first have to define that yourself somewhere, or get it from elsewhere (ie. module).

I would recommend you to look at this one: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Then restructure your code to look like this:

```
app.service('Notes', function($localStorage){
  this.$storage = $localStorage;

  this.saved = $localStorage.notes;
  this.entries = ($localStorage.notes!==null) ? JSON.parse(this.saved) :
    [{title: "Hey", desc: "This is a sample note. Add your own note by clicking the button below. :)"}];
});
```

You did have a few minor issues with that plunkr (tether not linked, wrong sequence of loading libraries (bootstrap/jQuery)), but the main issue was the use of the localStorage service.

Have a look at the corrections in my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K6EKlv1LvJOzKTQo154O?p=preview

Comment: Sometimes, after refreshing the notes itself disappears. And when I used the same code in another plunk, it refuses save new notes or read the sample hello note. @Nils

Answer (score 0):

1) put link

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

2) need `ngStorage` to inject

```
  var app = angular.module('noteMate', ['ngRoute','ngStorage']);
```

check example [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yEftkG8Eatyl1QlByObl?p=preview)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and still output. Can you please provide an edit my plunk given in link to illustrate the problem?

Comment: this plunk isn't working. It doesn't display the saved notes at all